# Does closing a stream block the thread?

Tags: c#, stream

I am saving data into file periodically (file is opened and closed every time) and I want to measure time taken by file operations using `Stopwatch`.

Should I include into measurement time taken by `Close()`?

---

We have problem with software and I suspect file operations, e.g. busy HDD or some kind of failures what may cause a delay. Will calling `Close()` in this case cause a delay (blocking) or is `Close()` a non-blocking method (but somewhere deep inside framework/winapi file is being flushed from write buffers, etc. after it) ?

Or maybe `Write()` will be slow in case of failures? I have no idea how to simulate disk problem to quickly test what will happens.

Comment: Either the time taken to close the file is too small to matter, or it isn't.  How are you planning on finding out which of those is true without measuring it?

Comment: You cannot get meaningful measurements.  You never write directly to disk, you write to the file system cache.  A memory-to-memory copy, very fast.  It gets written to the disk lazily, long after you closed the file.  This *can* go wrong, happens when the file system cache is filled to capacity.  Either because you write too much or because other programs do or because the machine doesn't have enough RAM or the disk is too slow or fragmented.  Your Write() will then be blocked until space is freed up, that can take a while.  Very random, very hard to predict.

Comment: Once I had logger configured to open/close file every time a message is written to it and revealed a very strange issue: in this case time for writing a message grown proportionally to log file size. Occasionally writing just a single message took 0.3 sec.  Keeping FileStream opened immediately hugely increased performance (and time for writing a message became constant, not depending on file size). So I suspect Open/Close operation on file is synchronous by default (I heard .NET 5 has async analogues). So if you know you need this file and write often, I recommend trying to keep it opened.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for explaining. So only `Write` has to be measured (to see if it suddenly takes too long time to finish). `Close` and `Open` (right?) are fast.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, [the documentation for `FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) recommends calling `Dispose` rather than `Close`.  Checking the reference source, all `Close` does is:

```
Dispose(true);
GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
```

> Will calling Close() in this case cause a delay (blocking) or is
>   Close() a non-blocking method (but somewhere deep inside
>   framework/winapi file is being flushed from write buffers, etc. after
>   it) ?

`Close` calls `Dispose`, which does two things:

1. Close the File Handle.
2. Flush any pending writes to disk (by default writes are buffered).

Of course, "Flush any pending writes to disk" means, tell the OS to "Flush any pending writes to disk." The OS handles differently depending on various factors (e.g., USB drives tend to be written less lazily and temp files might never be flushed to disk).

Comment: Not my downvote, but you aren't answer to my question: does calling `Close` blocks caller or not (I've feeling you are saying `No`)? @HansPassant comment explains what `Write` will be blocking caller in case of problems.